# systemd launch application on boot

Tags: linux, systemd, agetty

All,

I want to setup "Kiosk" mode on a real terminal with systemd. My initial approach was setup autologin with systemd and run the application from .bashrc. However the user is able to breakout to shell in this approach.

What I would like to achieve is at bootup, the application auto-launches and if it crashes respawns again. Any suggestion or pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Is this a real terminal or a virtual terminal?

Comment: It will be a real terminal

Comment: That's the complex case.  Is it dial-up (i.e. remote) or directly attached (local)?  All of this information needs to be in your question, for answerers to see.